# Extract/Scrape values from HTML

Tags: html, bash, shell, grep

I'd like to create a script that grabs two values from this awful HTML published on a city website:

558.35

and

66.0

These are water reservoir details and change weekly.

I'm unsure what the best tool to do this is, grep?

Thanks for your suggestions, ideas!

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Currently:</td>
            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 558.35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Percent of capacity:</td>
            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;66.0%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you use PHP then you could use DOMDocument.

Comment: Is this a skill you hope to improve on? Then learn python-scrapy, beautifulSoup and others. Python has a healthy eco-system for web scraping, but as html gets more baroque, you'll have to keep that skill up-to-date to be meaningful. If you're looking just to grab those 2 values and won't be doing anything else for years, the post a bounty for an `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` solution. If its really this simple, you might also find an `awk` solution, but once that data proves more complex than what you've indicated here, all bets are off ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, these are solutions I'll explore!

Comment: Regular expression is the worst tool to parse/scrape HTML. you may be interested in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using regex you can use sed

```
sed -nr 's#^[ ]*<td>.*;[ ]?([0-9]+[.][0-9]+)[%]?</td>[ ]*$#\1#p' my_html_file
```

An Htmlparser such as python's module BeautifulSoup or a javascript approach is a safer choice

**EDIT:**

Here is a snippet using javascript..results is logged to the console and an alert box pops up to show results

```js
var values="";
for(i=1;i<document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;++i){
values+=" "+document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;|Percent of capacity:|[ %]/g,"")
}
alert(values);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Currently:</td>
            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 558.35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Percent of capacity:</td>
            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;66.0%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```